# Get function's 'namespace path'

Tags: python

I have some namespaces, one included in the other:

```
class A:
    class B:
        class C:
            def method(): pass

get_ns_path(A.B.C.method) # >>> 'A.B.C.method'
```

Is it possible to implement such `get_ns_path(func)`  that receives a method/function and returns the 'namespace path' as a string?

`A.B.C.method.im_class` gives `C`, great, but how to go further up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think that is possible:

```
>>> dir(A.B.C)
['__doc__', '__module__', 'method']
```

More convincingly, there's no reason `A.B.C` should know about `A.B`, because you can do `Z.C = A.B.C` and they would be the same object. So what would `get_ns_path(Z.C.method)` return?

Answer (score -1):

Youn can get the *mro* using the [`inspect`](http://docs.python.org/library/inspect.html) module.

```
inspect.getmro(cls)¶
```

Comment: MRO works for inheritance, not for inclusion in namespaces :)

Comment: @o_O Tync `'.'join(reversed(inspect.getmro(method.im_class)))` ?

Comment: MRO is something different: `inspect.getmro(A.B.C.f.im_class) >>> (<class __main__.C at 0x1d78d70>,)`

Comment: The answer by @Robin is correct. Features don't know in which namespace they were declared.