# In Python, how can I determine which class a method was declared in?

Tags: python, introspection, decorator

How can I get a reference to the class a method was declared in? In the code below, I'm trying to get a reference to `Classical` in `test`.

```
class Classical:
    def method():
        pass

def test(func):
    # How can I get a reference to 'Classical' using only 'func'?
    pass

test(Classical.method)
```

I've tried `dir()`ing and searching, to no avail. Any ideas? (If it matters, I'm running Python 3.1)

**EDIT:** Changed the code to make more sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function decorator `test()` is executed in the context of the class `Classical` while this class is being created.  While executing the code in the class body, the class does not exist yet, so there is no means of accessing it.  You should use a [class decorator](http://docs.python.org/whatsnew/2.6.html#pep-3129-class-decorators) instead of a function decorator to work around this.

Alternatively, you can tell us what you are actually trying to achieve.  Most probably, there will be a simple solution.

**Edit**: To answer your edited question:  To access the class an unbound method belongs to, you can use `unbound_method.im_class` in CPython 2.x.  I don't know if this is portable to other Python implementations, and most probably there is a better way of achieving whatever you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Would there be a way to determine the class after the class and method are created? For example, if after the class body I called `test(Classical.method)`?

Comment: @zildjohn01: In CPython, you could use `func.im_class` to access the class of an unbound method, but I'd recommend against using this.  Probably there is a better solution to your problem.  And we could tell you, if you tell us what you are trying to achieve :)

Comment: @zildjohn: Again, hard. From the looks of `dir(Classical.method)`, not possible at all. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4707288/get-functions-namespace-path

Comment: Dunno about Python 3, but in Python 2 you can use `Classical.method.im_class`.

Comment: In Python 3, it's not possible as the wrapper for unbound methods is eliminated, `Classical.method` is just a function.

Comment: @Sven I'm trying to create a decorator to automatically copy docstrings and such from base classes to derived classes, instead of having an ugly `__getitem__.__doc__ = Base.__getitem__.__doc__` after every method. Looks like a solution is possible with two decorators, but the purist in me was hoping for a solution with one, heh.

Comment: @delnan @kwatford Unfortunately I'm running Python 3.

Comment: `im_class` gives the class that *asked* for the member, in other words whose descriptors returned the unbound method. So if you do `SomeOtherClass.method = Classical.method` it depends on which class object you use to access it. This whole thing is gone in Python3.

Comment: @zild: Shouldn't it be possible with a (single) class decorator?

Comment: @zildjohn01: This sounds like something that should be done in a class decorator:  Iterate over all members of `cls.__dict__`, and if they are lacking a docstring, look for the same function in the classes in `cls.__mro__`.  You should use new-style classes for this.

Comment: @zildjohn01: Btw, "automatically copy docstrings and such from base classes to derived classes" does actually sound like a bad idea. You overwrite the method, change it's implementation, but copy the original docstring that could be completely wrong now?

Comment: @Sven, I guess that's what I'll do then. I'm not sure if "explicit is better than implicit" applies here, but I liked having a decorator on the method if that's what was actually being modified. I'll probably still use both, storing a temporary flag in the function. It seems to be working fine, thanks for the guidance.

Comment: @zildjohn01: Actually, considering Jochen's last comment, the solution with two decorators sounds reasonable to avoid accidentally copying the docstring.

Comment: @Jochen That's why I'm also using a decorator on the method, to keep things explicit. Also, when I override a method, I at least try to keep to the contract of the base method. Sometimes there's nothing more to say than what's already been said.